# Play Framework - How to map web data to object data

Tags: java, data-binding, playframework

Imagine the following scenario:

I send a request to a service (which uses Play framework) with the following parameters (parameter's name should be underscored by convention):

`first_name=James&second_name=Parker`

Moreover I have a model class in my codebase which looks like this.

```
public class User {
    @Constraints.Required
    private String firstName;

    @Constraints.Required
    private String secondName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getSecondName() {
        return secondName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }

}
```

All I want to do is to map parameter's names with the corresponding
field names. The following statement using Play Framework fails because
User object cannot be initialized with the given parameters of request.

```
Form<User> form = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this first: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaRouting

And then:

```
GET    /myMethod/:firstName/:seccondName    controllers.MyController.myMethod(firstName: String, seccondName: String)
```

and simple Method:

```
public myMethod(String firstName, String lastName) {
    User u = new User();
    u.setFirstName(firstName);
    u.setSeccondName(seccondName);
}
```

Obviously if you use play framework 2.

Comment: Actually, this is not what I am looking for. All I want is to render a form of a User object for the validation of it based on the HTTP form data. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaForms

Answer (score 0):

You have underscores in the request parameter names, yet your class has the members in camelCase (e.g. `first_name` vs `fistName` [Missing a `r` here]).

Secondly it also seems like these class members are  declared private AND you have no setter methods only getters (i.e. setFirstName).

In order to do the binding your class is instantiated and the values are set and with no way to do so it will fail.

Once you've fixed the above, you should be able to bind and then call `form.hasErrors()` to check if validation has failed.

Hope that helps.

**Update:**

To handle the mismatch between the request parameter names and the class member names you would probably have to manually set things up.

In your controller method you would do something like this:

```
Map<String, String[]> reqBody = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded()
Map<String, String[]> newReqBody = new HashMap<>();

for(Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry: body.entrySet()) {
    newBody.put(underscoreToCamelCase(entry.key()), entry.value());
}

Form<User> form = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest(newReqBody);
```

Note that I'm using the overloaded version of `bindFromRequest` as seen [here](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/play/data/Form.html#bindFromRequest-java.util.Map-java.lang.String...-)

You should then implement the `underscoreToCamelCase` method in a generic enough way to handle all your conventions (Perhaps you might have a situation where there are more than one underscores).

Comment: First of all, I am sorry because my question was not very clear. I want to keep the underscore in the request parameters by convention as well as I want to keep camelCase for the Java fields. Therefore, what I want is a custom mapping for the underscored parameter's name and the corresponding Java field name.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get automatic binding for free unless the parameter names match the class members/fields. Your best bet will be to  manually transform the request map into the correct format. See my update in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I had in my head but I was looking for a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Not sure if you've already found your elegant solution but... the best that I could think of is to do the same mapping as above (underscore to camelCase) but at the global level. This can be done by overriding the `onRequest` method in Play's Global Settings (see [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaInterceptors)). Atleast that way you wouldn't have to repeat your self in every controller method.